# How can I use multiple refs to move focus among inputs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

In a legacy project I have [React Bootstrap V3](https://react-bootstrap-v3.netlify.app/components/forms/).

I need to move the focus on next input text. E.g. if user has been inserted the number into first input, focus need to be on second input. And goes on.

I know that I need to use the `ref`, but I cannot understand how use multiple refs.

This is my code:

```js
export default class OtpInput extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      otp: "12",
    };
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log("Update!");
    console.log("this.inputControlRef ################", this.inputControlRef);
  }

  setOtp(e) {
    // Only to invoke the componentDidUpdate()
    this.setState({
      otp: "21",
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form className="otpInput">
        <Row>
          <Col xs={2}>
            <FormGroup controlId="otpInput1">
              <FormControl
                inputRef={(ref) => {
                  this.inputControlRef = ref;
                }}
                type="text"
                value={
                  this.state && this.state.otp.length > 0 && this.state.otp[0]
                }
                onChange={(e) => this.setOtp(e)}
              />
            </FormGroup>
          </Col>
          <Col xs={2}>
            <FormGroup controlId="otpInput2">
              <FormControl
                inputRef={(ref) => {
                  this.inputControlRef = ref;
                }}
                type="text"
                value={
                  this.state && this.state.otp.length > 1 && this.state.otp[1]
                }
                onChange={(e) => this.setOtp(e)}
              />
            </FormGroup>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

With my code in inputControllerRef I have only the last one input text.

I tried

```js
<FormControl
                inputRef={(ref) => {
                  this.inputControlRef[0] = ref;
                }}
                type="text"
                value={
                  this.state && this.state.otp.length > 0 && this.state.otp[0]
                }
                onChange={(e) => this.setOtp(e)}
              />
```

at the first input but I got `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting '0')`

Comment: Tags belong in... the tags, not your title. See [ask]. Also, a front-end developer should almost never dump a URL into a page, even for an SO question. Create a proper link for best usability and accessibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*In Class Based components*

Define something like that in the constructor

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.formControl = [];
}
```

Add your components like below

```
<FormControl
  inputRef={(el) => this.formControl[0] = el}
  type="text"
  value={this.state && this.state.otp.length > 0 && this.state.otp[0]}
  onChange={(e) => this.setOtp(e)}
/>
<FormControl
  inputRef={(el) => this.formControl[1] = el}
  type="text"
  value={this.state && this.state.otp.length > 1 && this.state.otp[1]}
  onChange={(e) => this.setOtp(e)}
/>
```

Access the first one this way

```
componentDidUpdate() {
  console.log("Update!");
  console.log("First Form Control", this.formControl[0]);
}
```

Take this as reference: https://codesandbox.io/s/gw6rp2?file=/App.js&utm_medium=sandpack

Answer (score 0):

Use a ref callback instead of a ref object for multiple DOM references.
[React Offical Docs - Ref Callback](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/components/common#ref-callback)